# 100% CPU Utilization troubleshooting on db2 server

Tags: db2

whenever we are hitting bunch of commands on database, its CPU utilization is going to 100%, is there any idea about setting of db2 server changes or anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some research to understand what's happening. As you gave no facts about your environment or workload, you must do the work.

Here are some links that may help, which are for Db2 on Linux/Unix/Windows ( If your Db2 server is running on Z/OS or i-series then different tooling is necessary ) :

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/DB2PerfTips/entry/db2pd_the_hidden_gem?lang=en

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0055242.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0070123.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0025222.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0056368.html

Comment: @Govind try again